# Spring: Create Meta-Annotation for @ModelAttribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a lot of controllers with this code:

```
@RequestMapping("/test1")
public String test (@ModelAttribute("page") Page page) {
...
}

@RequestMapping("/test2")
public String test2 (@ModelAttribute("page") Page page) {
...
}
```

Is it possible to create a Meta-Annotation in Spring (4.3) that shortens this Annotation like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/test3")
public String test2 (@MyCustom Page page) {
...
}
```

So @ModelAttribute("page") will become @MyCustom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that won't work work. [As you can see in the sources](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.java), `ModelAttribute` is annotated

```
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.METHOD})
```

[which means it can be applied to methods and method parameters only](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Target.html). For a meta annotation, it would have to be applied on type level.

See [Spring Annotation Programming Model](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Annotation-Programming-Model) for details, but basically this is an edge case where Meta annotations just don't work.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! So I can give up searching :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an elegant solution for this:
We use the "HandlerMethodArgumentResolver" to check for Arguments of type "Page". If we found one, we get it out of the model and that's it.

This leads to this:

```
@RequestMapping("/test3")
public String test2 (Page page) {
...
}
```